# SQL query to get the lowest salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have been given a task to get the lowest salary of all employees of each department and job (ignoring the commission earned) from our SQL Server database.

Here is an example:

| emp_id | emp_name | job_name | manager_id | hire_date | salary | commission | dep_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 68319 | KAYLING | PRESIDENT |  | 1991-11-18 | 6000.00 |  | 1001 |
| 66928 | BLAZE | MANAGER | 68319 | 1991-05-01 | 2750.00 |  | 3001 |
| 67832 | CLARE | MANAGER | 68319 | 1991-06-09 | 2550.00 |  | 1001 |
| 65646 | JONAS | MANAGER | 68319 | 1991-04-02 | 2957.00 |  | 2001 |
| 67858 | SCARLET | ANALYST | 65646 | 1997-04-19 | 3100.00 |  | 2001 |
| 69062 | FRANK | ANALYST | 65646 | 1991-12-03 | 3100.00 |  | 2001 |
| 63679 | SANDRINE | CLERK | 69062 | 1990-12-18 | 900.00 |  | 2001 |
| 64989 | ADELYN | SALESMAN | 66928 | 1991-02-20 | 1700.00 | 400.00 | 3001 |
| 65271 | WADE | SALESMAN | 66928 | 1991-02-22 | 1350.00 | 600.00 | 3001 |
| 66564 | MADDEN | SALESMAN | 66928 | 1991-09-28 | 1350.00 | 1500.00 | 3001 |
| 68454 | TUCKER | SALESMAN | 66928 | 1991-09-08 | 1600.00 | 0.00 | 3001 |
| 68736 | ADNRES | CLERK | 67858 | 1997-05-23 | 1200.00 |  | 2001 |
| 69000 | JULIUS | CLERK | 66928 | 1991-12-03 | 1050.00 |  | 3001 |
| 69324 | MARKER | CLERK | 67832 | 1992-01-23 | 1400.00 |  | 1001 |

Expected output

| emp_id | emp_name | job_name | manager_id | hire_date | salary | commission | dep_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 68319 | KAYLING | PRESIDENT |  | 1991-11-18 | 6000.00 |  | 1001 |
| 66928 | BLAZE | MANAGER | 68319 | 1991-05-01 | 2750.00 |  | 3001 |
| 67832 | CLARE | MANAGER | 68319 | 1991-06-09 | 2550.00 |  | 1001 |
| 65646 | JONAS | MANAGER | 68319 | 1991-04-02 | 2957.00 |  | 2001 |
| 65271 | WADE | SALESMAN | 66928 | 1991-02-22 | 1350.00 | 600.00 | 3001 |
| 67858 | SCARLET | ANALYST | 65646 | 1997-04-19 | 3100.00 |  | 2001 |
| 63679 | SANDRINE | CLERK | 69062 | 1990-12-18 | 900.00 |  | 2001 |
| 69000 | JULIUS | CLERK | 66928 | 1991-12-03 | 1050.00 |  | 3001 |
| 69324 | MARKER | CLERK | 67832 | 1992-01-23 | 1400.00 |  | 1001 |

I tried this query below, but the problem is it returns only the job, dept and salary columns.

```
SELECT
    job_name, MIN(salary), dep_id
FROM 
    employees
GROUP BY
    dep_id, job_name;
```

```
 job_name  | salary  | dep_id
-----------+---------+--------
 PRESIDENT | 6000.00 |   1001
 MANAGER   | 2750.00 |   3001
 MANAGER   | 2550.00 |   1001
 MANAGER   | 2957.00 |   2001
 SALESMAN  | 1350.00 |   3001
 ANALYST   | 3100.00 |   2001
 CLERK     |  900.00 |   2001
 CLERK     | 1050.00 |   3001
 CLERK     | 1400.00 |   1001
(9 rows)
```

Can anyone help me how I can get the employee name as well?

Comment: What if there's only one person in a department and/or job? What if there's a tie (for highest salary, or second highest salary, or both)? For example, there are two analysts in dept_id 2001 with a salary of 3100. Why is scarlet in the output but not frank?

Comment: (e.g. you could argue that both have the highest and the lowest salary, or that neither of them has "the second highest." So what rule are you using to break the tie? Frank was hired first?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the logic and the contradiction (lowest vs. second highest) but to get the desired results it seems you want:

- for each department / job combo, lowest salary
- if a department / job combo only has one employee, get the only salary
- if there is a tie, the lowest is for the employee hired *later* (this is a guess, based on the desired output - Frank, for example, is left out of the output because he was hired earlier than Scarlet, and Wade, similarly, is left out because he was hired before Madden).

If any of these guesses are incorrect, please update the question with more detail.

```
SELECT emp_name, job_name, salary, dep_id 
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dep_id, job_name),
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dep_id, job_name 
                               ORDER BY salary DESC, hire_date)
  FROM dbo.employees
) AS RankedByDept 
WHERE rn = 2 OR c = 1;
```

- [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/MIZXiOkL)

The way you want the desired results ordered also isn't clear to me, and I don't know if there is a way to achieve that exact ordering with the information we have. Again, if there is reason to it (and that can be derived from the data), please update the question.

Comment: What about duplicates? You have lost two employees who, while not in the OP's Expected Output. meet their criteria,  If the purpose of the exercise is to find the lowest paid employees in each job, the duplicates should be there. Otherwise, why require employee names? We have insufficient info from the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I just reread your solution. What led you to the criterion "if there is a tie, the 2nd highest is for the employee hired later"

Comment: And why do you say " the 2nd highest salary" when the OP says "lowest salary"

Comment: @Nikkorian I made a guess, on how to break the tie, based on the desired output. They selected the answer, so I must have guessed right? Without any further info from the OP, we are where we are. As for highest vs. lowest, sure, that was a typo. An [earlier version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76983373/revisions) also mixed up highest and lowest, but it has since been corrected.

Answer (score -2):

`SELECT e.emp_name, job_name, MIN(salary), dep_id FROM  employees AS e GROUP BY dep_id, job_name;`

You may try this query to get the employee name as well.

Comment: No, this isn't MySQL, you can't just add arbitrary, ungrouped and non-aggregated columns to the `SELECT` list: `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1 / Column 'employees.emp_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
select emp_id,emp_name,job_name,manager_id,hire_date,salary commission,dep_id from employees
where concat(job_name,"|", salary,"|",dep_id) IN
    (SELECT
        concat(job_name,"|", MIN(salary),"|",dep_id) minsal
    FROM 
        employees
    GROUP BY
        dep_id, job_name);
```

EDIT================

RESULT
[image]

The OP has included an "expected result" with 9 rows, without offering a solution to the problem of duplicates. There are two employees in both 2001 and 3001 who share jobs and lowest salaries. My solution contains 11 rows and does match the OP's requirement to "get the lowest salary of all employees of each department and job" and to "get the employee name as well".

Comment: This returns [too many rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/a1VqPpRs), did you run it for yourself?